# Executing asynchronous method after class initialisation in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

I want to execute these lines of code after my application is initialized and the main window appears:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("token"))
{

    string[] startupStrings = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    await _myOneDrive.SilentLogIn();
    IsActive = true;
    if (startupStrings.Length > 1 && startupStrings[1] == "/a")
    {
        IsWorking = true;
        IsActive = false;
        await _myOneDrive.EjectSynchroProcedure(false);
        IsActive = true;
        IsWorking = false;
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am unable to do this because I can't use `await` operator in my MVVM model constructor. Signing up for `Loaded` event destroys the whole idea of MVVM. I've read not to use `async void` generally but only in a logical equivalent of Event Handler. So my async Commands look like this:

```
async void SilentLogin(object parameter)
{
    await _myOneDrive.SilentLogin();
    IsActive = true;
}
```

Then I initialize them in my constructor and bind commands to buttons in XAML code.

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    _myOneDrive = new MyOneDriveClient(PathPcDirectory, PathOneDriveDirectory, this);
    LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);
    SilentLoginCommand = new RelayCommand(SilentLogin);
    Console = "Program started";
}
```

It works just fine but I still cannot accomplish my goal of running the code after initialization. I can't await my `async void Login(object parameter)` command because it's `void` not `Task`. What is more, I can't change it to `Task` because it isn't valid with `RelayCommand`. So I am in this loop and would really use some hints, tips or just pointing out my mistakes.

Comment: I see no problem calling ViewModel's `Initialize` method from Loaded event of View. I don't think it violates MVVM.

Comment: I agree with @Euphoric. The View _is_ know about VM. View binding to it and using it. The goal of MVVM is for VM _not_ to worry about how its properties will be represented in View, but it doesn't mean that View shouldn't know how to work with VM.

Comment: Thanks. It obviously works fine. I took it to my hearth not to use code-behind but it seems to be better solution. I've tried using `Dispatcher` but it started to early.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with using codebehind for UI tasks.  Don't fall into that trap.  I would have suggested using the Dispatcher, but I would have told you to specify a very low `DispatcherPriority` so that your initializing of the view model happens after, say, data binding has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhen i had a similar issue and found a very simple implementation of an AsyncRelayCommand.

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : RelayCommand
{
    private readonly Func<Task> _asyncExecute;

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute)
        : base(() => asyncExecute())
    {
        _asyncExecute = asyncExecute;
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<Task> asyncExecute, Action execute)
        : base(execute)
    {
        _asyncExecute = asyncExecute;
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        return _asyncExecute();
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _asyncExecute();
    }
}
```

Then just modify your method to return Task and replace the usage of RelayCommand by your newly created AsyncRelayCommand. Worked fine for me.

Please note that the usage with a parameter probably won't work yet, so you need some additional implementation on this. For my case it wasn't necessary. But you should get the basic idea.

Comment: You're right. It worked fine. Nevertheless it worked also using simple `RelayCommand` and `async void`. What was my problem was how to eject that command or await a function on start. I decided to use `Loaded` event.